# How do I integrate Mercurial into Coda?

Tags: macos, version-control, mercurial, coda

I tried using the plugin from app Changes, but it doesn't work, it says "No SCM found".

Does anyone have a way to integrate Mercurial into Coda or know how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's not implemented yet, see the comment on their blog @http://www.panic.com/blog/2010/10/panic-state-of-the-union/... somewhere down the page "I would just like to throw out a feature request for Coda 2: Mercurial support."

Comment: @evandrix: Your comment answers it. I've searched the web (even though I don't use Coda) for an answer, but this question is outdated. The plugin doesn't exist anymore and Coda only seems to have git support. You should put it in as an answer, so this question doesn't look unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It's not implemented yet, see the comment on their [blog](http://panic.com/blog/2010/10/panic-state-of-the-union)... somewhere down the page "I would just like to throw out a feature request for Coda 2: Mercurial support."